# Can I say that $E[X | c] = E[c | X]$, when $c$ is a constant and $X$ is a random variable?

Tags: conditional-expectation, conditional

$X$ is a random variable defined in a sample space
$c$ is a constant $\in R$ (real numbers).

Comment: If $X$ is constant with value $c$ then why not?

Answer (score 6):

No to the question in the title. It can happen but that is a special case.

---

If $c$ is looked at as random variable defined on the same space as $X$ then $\mathbb E[X\mid c]$ is a random variable that can only take one value. This because by definition it is measurable wrt $\sigma(c)=\{\varnothing,\Omega\}$.

Further its expectation must equalize the expectation of $X$.

These two facts together leave only one choice: $\mathbb E[X\mid c]=\mathbb EX$.

Further we have $\mathbb E[c\mid X]=c$ because $\sigma(c)=\{\varnothing,\Omega\}\subseteq\sigma(X)$.

That together tells us that: $$\mathbb E[X\mid c]=\mathbb E[c\mid X]\iff \mathbb EX=c$$

Answer (score 2):

You cannot condition on a constant, so I guess you mean constant random variable. A constant random variable is [independent of any other random variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1585379/independence-between-a-constant-random-variable-and-another-random-variable), [so](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation)

$$
E[X|c]=E[X]
$$

So you're asking if $E[X]$ is equal to $c$s value.

Comment: no, I mean a constant. This is the question: Let X, Y be random variables defined on a sample space and c ∈ R a constant. State with
brief explanation whether the following statements are true or false. 

(i) E[X | c] = E[c | X]

Comment: @Raffaela there is no such a thing like conditioning on a constant or expected value of a constant. You'd need to invent your own probability theory for that.

Comment: That's why I don't get my professor's question... But I will use your answer, anyways, thanks!

Comment: @Raffaela you need to ask them what they meant, at face value it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Raffaela If this question has been asked to you by a professor then IMV you are fully justified to interpret the constant as a constant random variable (hence to use this answer). I think the professor must have had this way out in mind too. If not then the blame is on the professor (not on you).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe translating to an applied example will help illustrate why the equality typically doesn't hold (see the other answers for the special cases in which it does). I will use conditioning a bit hand-waivingly here as an information set rather than as proper conditional distributions.

Take $c$ to be the constant $\pi$ and $X$ the outcome of a coin flip, heads or tails. If you knew that $c$ equals $3.14...$, would that alter your expectation $E(X)$? No, I suppose, so $$E(X)=E(X|c)=1/2$$ (assuming a fair coin).

Conversely, if you knew the outcome of the coin flip, would that alter your expectation regarding $E(c)$? No, I suppose, so $E(c)=E(c|X)=3.14...$

So my hunch is your professor wanted to illustrate that conditional expectations do not "commute".